# Word-wrap inside a centered div does not work

Tags: css, word-wrap

My word-wrap does not work in a div with a specific class.

Check my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d7zjt408/1/

In a normal div, word-wrap works as it should:

```
<div class="back" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
  <h4>Konsequentialismus</h4>
</div>
```

However, as soon as I add this class, word-wrap stops working:

```
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center }
```

As you can see in the fiddle, in the second div, the word "Konsequentialismus" is not broken, as in the first div. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your word is broken fine in the second div for me. Is it a particular browser you're having trouble with?

Comment: You can just add `word-break: break-word` to `.centered` as demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/d7zjt408/2/

Comment: I just viewed it with firefox, chrome and opera, and the word is not broken in every browser. With what browser are you viewing it?

Comment: It seems to work fine in Firefox [if you add a `max-width` to your header](https://jsfiddle.net/d7zjt408/3/). I don't know that much about flex, though...

Comment: @MattGibson Yes, your solution works in Firefox as well. If you post it as an answer, I can accept it. Can you maybe explain, why max width solves the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this also without flex

```
.centered h4{
  text-align:center;
 position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%); }
```

```css
h4 {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -o-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  text-align: left;
}

.centered h4{
  text-align:center;
 position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%); }
```

```html
<div class="back" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
  <h4>Konsequentialismus</h4>
</div>
<br>

<div class="back centered" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
  <h4>Konsequentialismus</h4>
</div>
```